# Sending a custom POST https request in dispatch (+cookies, + headers)

Tags: scala, http, cookies, scala-dispatch

There is some documentation about sending post request in dispatch http://dispatch.databinder.net/Combined+Pages.html  but yet it's not clear. What are myRequest and myPost there?

I want to send a https post request + add some cookies manually via headers + add some customs headers like form data, etc, and then read the response by reading the headers and cookies.

I only know how to prepare url for sending post request:

```
val url = host(myUrl + "?check=1&val1=123").secure
```

What do I do next?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dispatch is built on top of [Async Http Client](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client).  Therefore, `myRequest` in the example:

```
 val myRequest = url("http://example.com/some/path")
```

is [com.ning.http.client.RequestBuilder](http://sonatype.github.io/async-http-client/apidocs/reference/com/ning/http/client/RequestBuilder.html).

Calling the `POST` method on `RequestBuilder` turns the request into a POST request.  That's what's happening in the `myPost` example:

```
def myPost = myRequest.POST
```

I often find the Dispatch documentation difficult to follow.  For a quick overview of the all the various Dispatch operators, see: [Periodic Table of Dispatch Operators](http://www.flotsam.nl/dispatch-periodic-table.html)

If you're asking how to build a POST request and add custom form parameters, you probably want to use the `<<(values)` operator like this:

```
val params = Map("param1" -> "val1", "param2" -> "val2") 
val req = url("http://www.example.com/some/path" <<(params)
```

Likewise if you want to add some custom headers you can use the `<:<(map)` operator like this:

```
val headers = Map("x-custom1" -> "val1", "x-custom2" -> "val2") 
val req = url("http://www.example.com/some/path" <<(params) <:<(headers)
```

*Update:* Actually, there is no `POST` method on `RequestBuilder`.  The call to `POST` is part of Dispatch and calls `setMethod` on the underlying `RequestBuilder`.  See [dispatch.MethodVerbs](https://github.com/dispatch/reboot/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/requests.scala) for more details.

Comment: I think it's vise versa: <:< adds headers, << form parameters.

Comment: @Alex, I'm pretty sure I got it right.  But your comment is one reason why I dislike all those crazy Dispatch operators. :-)  In some cases I think it's clearer to call methods on `RequestBuilder` directly, such as: `req.addHeader("x-custom1", "val1")`.